# Python: Count and Remove duplicates in the list of list

Tags: python, list, count, duplicates

I have a list of list:

```
a = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], 
     [1.0]
    ]

a= set(a)
```

What I need to do is removing all the duplicates in the list of list and keep the previous sequence. In addition, I need to count the number for each duplicates in the list. Such as

The list of list after removing the duplicates:

```
a = [[1.0],
     [2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 5.0],
     [5.0], 
     [1.0]
    ]
```

The count number of duplicates in the list of list

```
b = [[13],
     [6, 5, 4],
     [8, 3],
     [1, 3, 3],
     [3], 
     [1]
    ]
```

My code:

```
for index, lst in enumerate(a):
    seen = set()
    a[index] = [i for i in lst if i not in seen and seen.add(i) is None]
```

Comment: Is the list always ordered that nicely? Or could the inputs be mixed in any order?

Comment: The list should be always ordered nicely.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question or issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], 
     [1.0]
    ]

b = []
c = []

for inner in a:
    new_b = []
    new_c = []
    for value, repeated in groupby(sorted(inner)):
        new_b.append(value)
        new_c.append(sum(1 for _ in repeated))

    b.append(new_b)
    c.append(new_c)

print b
# [[1.0], [2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 5.0], [1.0, 4.0, 5.0], [5.0], [1.0]]
print c
# [[13], [6, 5, 4], [8, 3], [1, 3, 3], [3], [1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `collections.Counter()`

```
from collections import Counter

a = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], 
     [1.0]
    ]

dic_count = [ Counter(x) for x in a]

print dic_count

'''
[
    Counter({1.0: 13}),
    Counter({2.0: 6, 3.0: 5, 4.0: 4}),
    Counter({3.0: 8, 5.0: 3}),
    Counter({4.0: 3, 5.0: 3, 1.0: 1}),
    Counter({5.0: 3}),
    Counter({1.0: 1})
]
'''

print [ x.keys() for x in dic_count ]

'''
[
     [1.0],
     [2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 5.0],
     [5.0],
     [1.0]
]
'''

print [ x.values() for x in dic_count ]

'''
[
    [13],
    [6, 5, 4],
    [8, 3],
    [1, 3, 3],
    [3],
    [1]
]
'''
```

Comment: +1 for Counter, although are `keys()` and `values()` guaranteed to yield values in the same order?

Comment: @kroolik: yes.  The order is arbitrary, but `keys()` and `values()` have to align unless the dictionary is modified between calls.

Comment: It should be - but I never checked this.

Comment: @DSM, you are right, as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Answer (score 1):

This is efficient:

```
b = [list(set(x)) for x in a]

c =  [[a[ind].count(x) for x in ele] for ind, ele in enumerate(b)]
```

Timings on a list of 50 sublists:

```
In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: b = []
   ...: c = []
   ...: for inner in a:
   ...:     new_b = []
   ...:     new_c = []
   ...:     for value, repeated in groupby(sorted(inner)):
   ...:         new_b.append(value)
   ...:         new_c.append(sum(1 for _ in repeated))
   ...:     b.append(new_b)
   ...:     c.append(new_c)
   ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 20.4 ms per loop

In [9]: %%timeit
    dic_count = [ Counter(x) for x in a]
    [ x.keys() for x in dic_count ]
    [ x.values() for x in dic_count ]
   ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 39.1 ms per loop

In [10]: %%timeit
    b = [list(set(x)) for x in a]
    c = [a[ind].count(x) for x in ele]for ind, ele in enumerate(b)]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 7.95 ms per loop
```

Comment: How to count the duplicate number in each list?

Comment: I will add that in a sec

Answer (score 1):

Hi you probably shouldn't use this code (I was just playing around with some new functions I haven't tried yet) but this gets you your desired output...

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import *
vals = zip(*(izip(*izip(row.keys(),row.values())) for row in (dict(Counter(each)) for each in a)))
print vals[0],"\n", vals[1]
```

If I were you I would just work off of this...

```
[dict(Counter(each)) for each in a]
```

Very clean output and more readable than my solution

Answer (score 0):

I had to develop something similar to this recently.  My solution was to iterate through the list and create an array that has the value along with the quantity of the value the original list contained.

```
    def count_duplicates(input_list):
        count_list = []
        for each in input_list:
            new_count = [each, input_list.count(each)]
            if count_list.count(new_count) >= 1:
                continue
            else:
                count_list.append(new_count)
        return count_list
```

By running the above function inside of a for-each loop and setting a new list equal to the list of lists, you could make an output that contains everything you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to go to extremes to find this out, it can be done with simple math.

```
the_list = [34, 40, 17, 6, 6, 48, 35, 8, 23, 41, 3, 36, 14, 44, 4, 46, 13, 26, 8, 41, 48, 39, 3, 43, 7, 20, 44, 17, 14, 18, 4, 3, 38, 42, 4, 19, 50, 38, 19, 40, 3, 26, 33, 26, 47, 46, 30, 12, 28, 32]
print(len(the_list) - len(list(set(the_list))))
```

With comments:

```
# list with duplicates
the_list = [34, 40, 17, 6, 6, 48, 35, 8, 23, 41, 3, 36, 14, 44, 4, 46, 13, 26, 8, 41, 48, 39, 3, 43, 7, 20, 44, 17, 14, 18, 4, 3, 38, 42, 4, 19, 50, 38, 19, 40, 3, 26, 33, 26, 47, 46, 30, 12, 28, 32]

# in actual lists where you don't know the amount of items,
# determine the amount with len()
list_size = len(the_list)

# remove the duplicates using set(),
# since there was no mention of converting
# we'll also convert back to list()
the_list = list(set(the_list))

# how many duplicates?
duplicates = list_size - len(the_list)

print(f"Total items in list: {list_size}")
print(f"Number of duplicates removed: {duplicates}")
```